# Reassigning TextVIew.Text reassigns text, then throws an exception in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, textview

I am trying to make a small activity where there is a TextView above a horizontal ProgressBar. I raise the progress bar progress to 100 slowly, then I want the TextView.Text to change and the ProgressBar.Progress to reset to 0 in order to show that we are now loading something else.

The strange behavior I am seeing is that when I run it, the TextView.Text actually changes like it is supposed to.  Then throws an exception stating that "Only the originial thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." I don't know why it would change and then throw the exception.  If I comment out the line where I reassign the TextView.Text, then the ProgressBar behaves correctly (resetting then loading again).  You would expect that to fail too, since the TextViewand the ProgressBar are both created in the same view hierarchy.  Here is my code:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Departure);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mainLinearLayout);

        Button departButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.departButton);
        departButton.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            layoutParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            textView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

            textView.Text = "Performing Pre-Departure Validation";

            linearLayout.AddView(textView);

            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, Android.Resource.Attribute.ProgressBarStyleHorizontal);
            progressBar.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            progressBar.Progress = 0;
            linearLayout.AddView(progressBar);

            (new Thread(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                while (progressBar.Progress < 100)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    progressBar.Progress += 5;
                }
                progressBar.Progress = 0;
                textView.Text = "Retrieving Hazardous Material Information..";
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                while (progressBar.Progress < 100)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    progressBar.Progress += 5;
                }
            })).Start() ;
        };
}
```

**UPDATE** 
I tried implementing Karandeep Atwal's suggestion and now the Activity does not display the TextView or the ProgressBar until the Run method has completed.

I changed the click event to

```
 departButton.Click += (s, e) =>
 {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            layoutParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            textView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

            textView.Text = "Performing Pre-Departure Validation";

            linearLayout.AddView(textView);

            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, Android.Resource.Attribute.ProgressBarStyleHorizontal);
            progressBar.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            progressBar.Progress = 0;
            linearLayout.AddView(progressBar);

            RunOnUiThread(new MyRunnable(progressBar, textView));
}
```

and added this Runnable to my class

```
    internal class MyRunnable : Java.Lang.Object, Java.Lang.IRunnable
    {
        private ProgressBar mProgressBar = null;
        private TextView mTextView = null;
        public MyRunnable(ProgressBar progressBar, TextView textView)
        {
            mProgressBar = progressBar;
            mTextView = textView;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            while (mProgressBar.Progress < 100)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                mProgressBar.Progress += 5;
            }
            mProgressBar.Progress = 0;
            mTextView.Text = "Retrieving ";
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            while (mProgressBar.Progress < 100)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                mProgressBar.Progress += 5;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: By the way, in case anyone is wondering, if I don't use a thread then neither the TextView or the Progress Bar show up until after the second time the ProgressBar has finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of my head, try something like the code below.
That way, all calls will be UI synchronized, Task.Delay would run asynchronously (thus won't block the UI thread).

```
departButton.Click += (s, e) =>
{
  var ignore = TestAsync();
}


async Task TestAsync() {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                while (progressBar.Progress < 100)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    progressBar.Progress += 5;
                }
                progressBar.Progress = 0;
                textView.Text = "Retrieving Hazardous Material Information..";
                await Task.Delay(100);
                while (progressBar.Progress < 100)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    progressBar.Progress += 5;
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside this ui thread .Usually, any action involving the user interface must be done in the main or UI thread, that is the one in which onCreate() and event handling are executed.

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {

//stuff that updates ui

}
});
```

Comment: Correct. Plus, much better, do such things with async/await and Tasks.

Comment: This solution does not work.  It does not display the TextView or the ProgressBar until the Run method has completed.  Please see my updated code to see how I implemented what you suggested.

Comment: Only parts that touch UI have to be synchronized, not your entire loop.